# Retorna Json de objeto em C# com Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Estou com um problema para retornar um Json usando Entity Framework. O código que estou usando é:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult Item(int agendaHorarioID)
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        IList<AgendaHorario> agendaHorario = db.AgendaHorario.Where(w => w.AgendaHorarioID == agendaHorarioID).ToList();
        var teste = agendaHorario.ToArray();
        return Json(new { HttpStatusCode.OK, dados = teste }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

O erro que acontece é:

```
A instância de ObjectContext foi descartada e não pode mais ser usada para operações que exijam uma conexão.
```

O motivo do problema eu sei, o objeto não foi transformado em um array para tirar a dependência do Entity Framework. Já tentei de várias formas mas não consegui.

Comment: Amigo, não trabalho com EF, e sim com NHibernate, e as coisas são similares, acredito que um caminho para sanar esse problema e trabalhar com DTO's na View, e serializar os objetos sem objetos de controle do ORM, outro caminho é sobrescrever seu serializador JSON, para ignorar objetos de controle do ORM, em NH eu faço algo [assim](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.WebApi.NH/Json/NHibernateProxyJsonConverter.cs), em EF deve haver algo simular. É apenas uma dica.

Comment: @marlon.tiedt aonde exatamente o erro para 
(qual linha), porque o que você fez deveria funcionar sem tal erro ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aparentemente esse problema ocorre por causa de referências usando lazy loading. Uma vez que o `Dispose()` é chamado por causa do bloco `using`, o `ERPContext` deixa de existir. Portanto, quando uma instância de `AgendaHorario` é serializada, ocorrem referências a algum atributo complexo, o lazy loading é disparado e procura o contexto que não existe mais.

Em vez de mandar todo objeto `AgendaHorario` (que poderia conter referências cíclicas), tente selecionar os campos que deseja retornar via JSON e utilize Include para incluir as propriedades complexas:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
public JsonResult Item(int agendaHorarioID)
{
    using (var db = new ERPContext())
    {
        var dados = db.AgendaHorario.Include(m => m.PropLazy).Where(m => m.AgendaHorarioID == agendaHorarioID).Select(m => new { m.Prop1, m.Prop2 }).ToList();            
        return Json(new { HttpStatusCode.OK, dados }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se a questão é apenas tirar a dependência do Entity Framework, basta enumerar o resultado.

```
IList<AgendaHorario> agendaHorario = db.AgendaHorario.Where(w => w.AgendaHorarioID == agendaHorarioID).ToList();
```

**EDIT**

Não conheço sua classe `AgendaHorario`, mas o atributo `[JsonIgnore]` evita carregar as propriedades que estão marcadas com ele. Quando preciso gerar um `JSON`, uso esse atributo pra evitar gerar informação demais e desnecessária.

Comment: Não, usar AsEnumerable não executa a query. Para executar a query pode chamar o .ToList() como o OP faz ou então usar o GetEnumerator().

Comment: @Crood pois .ToArray() que o OP faz não serve propósito nenhum dado que existe a transformação para .ToList(), logo não é a causa do problema.

Comment: @Crood so estava a concordar com a observação feita :) (e não tinha lido a edição do comentário relativamente ao Context)

Comment: Detalhei o problema na minha resposta anterior...

Comment: Errei o método. É o `ToList()` que defere o resultado. Vou atualizar.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tomar duas medidas para resolve isso, uma delas é desanexar(`detach`) o objeto do contexto, mas esse caso é recomendado quando é um objeto.

```
db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
```

No caso de lista, recomendaria remover o `Tracing`

```
db.AgendaHorario.AsNoTracking().Where(w => w.AgendaHorarioID == agendaHorarioID).ToList();
```